# Can I optimise a SQL select on fn_listextendedproperty?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've a c# project that runs few queries at startup. I was trying to find out if I can optimize the execution time. The other queries take less than 100 ms but this query is a bit slower.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default) 
  where name = 'CUSTOM_EX_PROP'
```

**301   ms**

Is it normal? Can this query be optimized? Is there a faster way to read the database extended property?

Here is my c# code in case

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew ();
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter (new SqlCommand (query, _con))) {
    sda.Fill (dt);
}
watch.Stop ();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print (query + "\r\n" + elapsedMs.ToString () + " ms");
```

EDIT - As @Liam pointed that it smells XY Problem, let me tell the actual scenario as well. The version of database is stored in its extended property and when I connect to database I just want to make sure the version is right. That is why I am reading its extended property at startup.

Comment: this whole thing smells of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: can you share execution plan as xml,i cant repro the issue on my system,i completes in less than a second,it must be specific to your system or query may be waiting for some resources

Comment: also see if this works for your case `select * from sys.extended_properties`

Comment: Is this really a problem?  I mean 301ms is still quick (an eye blink can take 400ms) and a user will not notice an extra 200ms as a one off action.  If you have multiple queries like this slowing the loading process down then it might be advisable to execute them in parallel and/or delay loading some data until after the form/page has loaded (assuming it is not needed immediately)

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION` will get you the version in probably no more than a couple of milliseconds. However, as jason.kaisersmith pointed out (though a bit more bluntly), Unless you are running this in a loop, optimizing 300 ms is complete nonsense.

Comment: @TheGameiswar How to share the plan!!!? BTW the query is a fast when I run it in SSMS...

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is not about sql server version. It is database version set by DBA.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, Actually it takes time randomly, e.g. my last run shows 3304 ms for this same query.. but If I run the same query in SSMS, it takes almost no time..

Comment: @TheGameiswar ..  select * from sys.extended_properties --- this works like a charm... now it takes 5 ms... You can post it as answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the code for fn_listextendedproperty shows it is from a view..but with bunch of other parameters which may not be needed for you

```
 insert @ids select object_id, name from sys.objects  
  where schema_id = @major  
  and parent_object_id = 0  
  and 0 <> charindex( '.'+type+'.',  
   case @level1type  
    when 'TABLE' then '.U .'  
    when 'VIEW' then '.V .'  
    when 'RULE' then '.R .'  
    when 'DEFAULT' then '.D .'  
    when 'QUEUE' then '.SQ.'  
    when 'SYNONYM' then '.SN.'  
    when 'AGGREGATE' then '.AF.'  
    when 'FUNCTION' then '.TF.FN.IF.FS.FT.'  
    when 'PROCEDURE' then '.P .PC.RF.X .'  
    when 'SEQUENCE' then '.SO.'  
    end )  
end  

-- Now get properties from id-s obtained, and return  
--  
insert @tab select @basetype, i.nam, p.name, p.value  
 from sys.extended_properties p join @ids i on p.class = @class and p.major_id = i.maj  
 where p.minor_id = 0 and (@name is null or @name = p.name)
```

so try selecting from the view itself and see if it is within your acceptable speed limits for your case

```
select * from 
sys.extended_properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot optimize system function;

If you don't like it, write your own function and use it instead of this one.

The text for this function can be obtained by executing

```
exec sp_helptext 'fn_listextendedproperty'
```